# dynamic drop box from query

Tags: php, sql

I want to display a drop box from the results of a query but I am getting the following error; where the drop box is , only $row is show no actual content

My code:

```
<?php
 $start=$_GET['arrival'];
 $end=$_GET['departure'];
 $type=$_GET['type'];

  $query = odbc_exec (odbc_connect("book", "", ""), "SELECT Location_id
  FROM PITCH
   WHERE (((PITCH.location_id) Not In (SELECT Location_Id FROM BOOKING
     WHERE StartDate OR EndDate 
     NOT BETWEEN
      #$start# -1  And #$end# +1)) AND ((PITCH.Type_name)='$type'))");
      $result = odbc_result_all($query);

       echo '<select name="type" id="type">
    While ($row = odbc_fetch_array ($result))

      {
         <option> $row </option>
     }
       </select>';

  ?>
```

Comment: echo your query and execute it within your DB manage software to see if it is correct. After query correction, I see you put <select> start and end tags inside the while loop. This shouldn't be the case. Your <select> tag should start before while loop and end tag after while loop. Within your while loop you should only echo <option> tag.

Comment: the query works fine, updated my php but just getting what ever i put inbetween the option tags inside the select drop box

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your code should be like:

```
<?php
$start     = isset($_GET['arrival']) ? trim($_GET['arrival']):null;
$end       = isset($_GET['departure']) ? trim($_GET['departure']):null;
$type      = isset($_GET['type']) ? trim($_GET['type']):null;

$query = odbc_exec (odbc_connect("book", "", ""), "
                     SELECT Location_id
                     FROM PITCH
                     WHERE (((PITCH.location_id) NOT IN (SELECT Location_Id FROM BOOKING
                     WHERE StartDate OR EndDate 
                     NOT BETWEEN #$start# -1  AND #$end# +1)) AND ((PITCH.Type_name)='$type'))
        ");
$result = odbc_result_all($query);

echo '<select name="type" id="type">';
While ($row = odbc_fetch_array ($result)) {
   echo "<option> $row </option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

You will see I used [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function on your $_GET fields. You should make it a habit as it checks whether your mentioned field is set or not - to prevent from errors.

Moreover, keep your error reporting on your development computer. Here is how you can:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Comment: thank you for you help, atm the drop down is empty and the results of the query are appearing above the select box

Comment: if i echo $result;  i just get a number of how many records there are ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 $start     = $_GET['arrival'];
  $end       = $_GET['departure'];
 $type      = $_GET['type'];

$query = odbc_exec (odbc_connect("book", "", ""), "
                 SELECT Location_id
                 FROM PITCH
                 WHERE (((PITCH.location_id) NOT IN (SELECT Location_Id FROM      
BOOKING
                 WHERE StartDate OR EndDate 
                 NOT BETWEEN #$start# -1  AND #$end# +1)) AND ((PITCH.Type_name)='$type'))
    ");
$option = "";
while($rows = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
$name = $rows["Location_id"];
$option.="<option>".$name."</option>";
}
?>
<p>Available Pitches
<select name="Pitch" id="Pitch">
<option value="0">Select a Pitch</option>
<?php echo $option?>
</select>
```